# Birth certificate in Solidity

Tags: solidity, contract-development

I nead to prepare a birth certificate to declare a newborn.

Does anyone know where I can find examples birth certificate with solidity ?

Comment: why not to deploy your own smart contract or use Uport

Comment: Might want to clarify your goal.  Are you creating one birth certificate for just one child, or a system for doing it for many children?  Do you just want to store an image of the birth certificate (https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/11987/how-does-data-storage-blockchain-works).